# Aggregate over difference of levels of factor in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given df1:

```
  A B C
0 a 7 x
1 b 3 x
2 a 5 y
3 b 4 y
4 a 5 z
5 b 3 z
```

How to get `df2` where for each value in `C` of `df1`, a new `col D` has the difference bettwen the `df1` values in `col B` where `col A==a` and where `col A==b`:

```
  C D
0 x 4
1 y 1
2 z 2
```

Comment: df.groupby('C').B.diff().dropna()

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a pivot table:

```
df = df1.pivot_table(columns = ['A'],values = 'B', index = 'C')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D': df['a'] - df['b']})
```

The risk in the answer given by @YOBEN_S is that it will fail if `b` appears before `a` for a given value of `C`